# API for Checking errors in passing arguments Desire2Learn

Tags: c#, desire2learn

I have written a API to create CreateCourseOffering in Desire2Learn

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#post--d2l-api-lp-(D2LVERSION-version)-courses-

I called the above API for that.Code exceuted fine and i dont find any course created .Pasting my code below. please suggest whats wrong in it

**My inputs**

```
        objCourse.Code = "1234567";
        objCourse.Name = "TCS_TestCourse2";
        objCourse.path = "/content/Traning";
        objCourse.ForceLocale = false;
        objCourse.ShowAddressBook = false;
        objCourse.CourseTemplateId = 10;
```

**MyCode**

```
    UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder(userContext.CreateAuthenticatedUri("/d2l      /api/lp  /1.0/courses/", "POST"));

            CreateCourse objCreateCourse = new CreateCourse();
            objCreateCourse.Code = objCourse.Code;
            objCreateCourse.Name = objCourse.Name;
            objCreateCourse.path = objCourse.path ;
            objCreateCourse.ForceLocale = objCourse.ForceLocale;
            objCreateCourse.ShowAddressBook = objCourse.ShowAddressBook;
            objCreateCourse.CourseTemplateId = objCourse.CourseTemplateId;

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string createCourseData = serializer1.Serialize(objCreateCourse);




            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri.Uri);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(createCourseData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
```

Comment: Have you checked the response you're getting from the service?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON parsing on the server side requires all fields to be included even if they are null. It looks like you are just missing a few of those fields.

I verified locally that the following JSON block successfully created a Course Offering. When I omitted the null fields it resulted in a 400 Bad Request:

```
var data = { 
        'Name': "TCS_TestCourse2",
        'Code': "1234567",
        'Path': "/content/Training",
        'CourseTemplateId': 10,
        'SemesterId': null,
        'StartDate': null,
        'EndDate': null,
        'LocaleId': null,
        'ForceLocale': false,
        'ShowAddressBook': false
    };
```

Assuming that CourseTemplateId: 10 is a valid orgunit number.

I would change this section of code to reflect that:

```
        CreateCourse objCreateCourse = new CreateCourse();
        objCreateCourse.Code = objCourse.Code;
        objCreateCourse.Name = objCourse.Name;
        objCreateCourse.path = objCourse.path ;
        objCreateCourse.ForceLocale = objCourse.ForceLocale;
        objCreateCourse.ShowAddressBook = objCourse.ShowAddressBook;
        objCreateCourse.CourseTemplateId = objCourse.CourseTemplateId;
        objCreateCourse.StartDate = null;
        objCreateCourse.EndDate = null;
        objCreateCourse.LocaleId = null;
        objCreateCourse.SemesterId = null;
```